# Find value in one column and print corresponding value from other one

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have text file with values as:

```
1 Peter
2 Paul
```

I need a command/scipt that will take as a parameter value from the second column (e.g. Paul) and return the corresponding value from the first one (2).

I'm trying to use while loop, but how can find the value I need:

```
while IFS= read -a line; do      
  printf "%s\n" "${line[@]}"     
done < "file.txt"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po ".* (?=Paul)" file
```

Output:

```
2
```

or with bash:

```
while read -r num name; do
  [[ $name == "Paul" ]] && printf "%s\n" "$num"
done < file
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` might come in handy in this scenario:

```
$ awk '$2 == "Paul" {print $1}' input.txt
2
```

Or interactively:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "Name: "; getline name < "-"} $2 == name {print $1}' input.txt
Name: Paul
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You may grep it first, then read the values, e.g.

```
grep -w Paul file.txt | while read v k; do echo $v; done
```

If you know `Paul` is the last column, use `Paul$`.